How to get a global position of a Widget in QToolbar?
I have the code:
auto toolbar = new QToolBar(&mainWidget);
toolbar->move(50,50); // random pos, but not (0,0);
toolbar->addWidget(new QPushButton("1-button"));
auto secondButton = new QPushButton("2-button");
toolbar->addWidget(secondButton);
qDebug() << secondButton->pos(); // (0,0) ok because there's local coords.
qDebug() << secondButton->mapToGlobal(QPoint{0,0}); // expected secondButton's global pos, but found toolbar pos. Why?

Also I had tried some variants of usage of methods 'geomtry' and 'rect' that followed to the same result. Using Qt 6.6.
How to get a global position of a Widget in QToolbar? Thanks.

It's not ok to have (0,0) even in the local coords because it's the second button, not the first one. And pos() is meant to return the position from the parent widget perpective.

My guess is that (0,0) is also the default value. And if you didn't add the tool bar into your window before calling pos(), it would return the default (0,0) because, well... it's not yet in the window to have a position.

As pointed out above you'll never get the final position until the parent has been eventually shown and/or added to an active layout. QToolBar is also peculiar as it's able to hide its own widgets when necessary. Besides, remember that you should always use addAction() (eventually use QWidgetAction if you need custom widgets).

The position is confirmed after showing.
#include "MainWindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    QToolBar* toolBar = new QToolBar();

    QPushButton *p1 = new QPushButton("1");
    QPushButton *p2 = new QPushButton("2");

    toolBar->addWidget(p1);
    toolBar->addWidget(p2);
    w.addToolBar(toolBar);
    qDebug() << "before Showing";
    qDebug() << p1->pos();
    qDebug() << p2->pos();
    qDebug() << p2->mapToGlobal(p2->geometry().topLeft());
    qDebug() << p2->mapToParent(QPoint(0, 0));
    w.show();
    qDebug() << "after Showing";
    qDebug() << p1->pos();
    qDebug() << p2->pos();
    qDebug() << p2->mapToGlobal(p2->geometry().topLeft());
    qDebug() << p2->mapToParent(QPoint(0, 0));

    return a.exec();
}

Result;
before Showing
QPoint(0,0)
QPoint(0,0)
QPoint(0,0)
QPoint(0,0)

after Showing
QPoint(10,2)
QPoint(85,2)
QPoint(730,220)
QPoint(85,2)


In theory, it may be enough to call activate() on the toolbar's layout.
